# Can vermicompost tea be used with aquaponics?

Tags: aquaponics, vermicomposting

Has anyone ever used vermicompost tea with aquaponics? I have found little formal research on the area and am curious if the two nitrogen cycles can be combined.

Comment: Are you doing organic?

Comment: Maybe, I am not certain if hydroponics or aquaponics can be certified organic under the USDAs guidelines for organic farming. I can say that in controlled environment agriculture, which is what I work in, we use no pesticides and minimal artificial fertilizers. My work focuses on optimizing alternative closed loop systems like the one described in my question. Vermicompost tea is rich with "natural" fertilizers that plants crave. *no not like brondo*

Comment: The question *Has everyone ever used* is not very relevant. Please [edit] your question and **ask your real question** (also in the title). There is a reason that you are asking this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I would mix the tea with the aquaculture, maybe feed the fish worms instead?

I think that by adding the nitrogen from the tea, you would just be adding more nitrogen to a system with it's own nitrogen input (fish poo), possibly more than the plants could take up, which could lead to algal blooms, and de-oxygenation, which might kill your fish.

Both are good systems, and perhaps could work together, the vermiculture taking inputs from roots and unused garden bits from the aquaculture, and the fish getting a wormy treat from time to time. 
Doubling the nitrogen at one point in one cycle makes less sense to me than combining the inputs and outputs of both systems.

I've not practiced either of these systems, so I'm just speculating.

Comment: I totally agree that it is very likely that excess nitrogen is a possible side effect and you are right again that algal blooms would deoxygenate the water. I use air stones and have dissolved oxygen sensors so thats not much of a risk.

What I am wondering about is how to massively scale aquaponics sustainably. I begin studying these systems in university where this idea was discussed but never pursued. Like I mentioned above I do a lot of work with sensors for monitoring so nitrogen sensors would be added to achieve optimum levels.

Thanks for the feedback!